# com.github.paulcwarren:spring-content-gcs does not have spring boot starter

Tags: google-cloud-storage, spring-content-community-project

I am using spring boot with google storage. I have been using before `spring-content-fs-boot-starter`. It was fine and working as expected. Now I am trying to use `spring-content-gcs` . since the boot stater is not available for the gcs. However it is not working as expected. Why boot starter is not available for the spring-content-gcs ? I see there is no enough documentation for the spring-content-gcs.

my gradle relevant dependencies are:

implementation 'com.github.paulcwarren:spring-content-gcs:3.0.6' implementation 'com.github.paulcwarren:spring-content-rest-boot-starter:3.0.6'`

the config class is as follows:

```
`@Configuration@EnableGCPStorage
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Value("${gcp.credentials.location}")
private String gcpKeyFile;
@Value("${gcp.project-id}")
private String gsProjectId;

@Bean
public Storage storage() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource(gcpKeyFile).getInputStream();

    return StorageOptions.newBuilder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream))
            .setProjectId(gsProjectId).build().getService();
}
}
```

I post the  entity it gets saved in database  which is fine. To add a content (image) I use put http method and add an image as binary which results in the following erorr:
No suitable HttpMessageConverter found to read request body into object of type class com.....Photo from request with content type of image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8"

Using spring-content-fs-boot-starter it was working fine.

How can we use spring-content-gcs in a spring boot application while using spring-content-rest-boot-starter.